# A way to notify parent thread when child thread was killed or interrupted

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a multithreading application in C#. Child threads do some serious work and I want know when child thread was killed to rerun it. What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: There is no such parent-child relationship between threads. You may call `Join` in your "child thread"

Comment: @MitchWheat maybe some exception was thrown or some system error occured

Comment: @MitchWheat can thread be killed without exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd be best off using the Task Parallel Library introduced in .NET 4. That way you can add a continuation to execute on failure (or cancellation, or success). Call [`Task.ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith.aspx) and pass in the continuation.

Tasks are generally the preferred approach to concurrency as of .NET 4. They compose well, they can represent operations which return values, they can represent asynchronous operations, they're the basis of async/await in C# 5... they're generally good :)

Answer (score 2):

There might be a way by passing the function of parent thread to a function being executed in children thread and attaching it to the delegate in children thread. Then in children thread execution function you should apply try-catch mechanism and call that delegate in the catch block.

For example create class like this:

```
public class Executor
{
    delegate void RunWhenFaild();

    void Execute(Action functionToBeExecuted, Action<Exception> callOnFailure)
    {
        RunWhenFaild += callOnFailure;

        try
        {
            functionToBeExecuted();
            RunWhenFaild -= callOnFailure;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            callOnFailure(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And then on your code create function which will be called on failure:

```
void OnFailure(Exception e)
    {
        //DO SMTH WITH IT
    }
```

And run it:

```
TaskFactory.StartNewTask(() => new Executor().Execute(workToDo, OnFailure));
```

This way your function OnFailure will be called from inside of the new task.

If not you can still create a loop in parent thread and periodicaly check status of all the children threads. But that's of course not recommended.